# Fix size of GridView item

Tags: android, xml, gridview

i'm trying to create app with rang of **images** i have this problem with `GridView`
The size varies each time ,all images have the same size **480x800** but when i `scroll` up or down size changes every time.i don't know reason ?

**fragment.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:background="#0e0e0e"
      tools:context=".Art">
  <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
  <GridView
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/gridViewCategory"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

**picture_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <ImageView
      android:background="#f6000000"
      android:layout_margin="2dp"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:src="@drawable/arrw"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:id="@+id/cat_imageView" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update `picture_item.xml` as below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:background="#f6000000"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/arrw"
        android:id="@+id/cat_imageView" />
 </LinearLayout
```

Comment: salam alaikum and thanks for reply please i want to ask you a another question why my app running slow when i moving between item ( navigation view ) Each item contains category and each category contains rang of images ( like this picture of post )  display them by URL please help me ??

Comment: Try using Glide or Picasso library to load image on ImageView. Both library are very easy to use.